# Rails: How can I access my database on my host machine (windows) from a virtualbox guest (ubuntu)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to setup my rails project (guest: ubuntu) so it can access the sql server database on my host os windows. I'm using virtual box but, I'm unsure what my "host" should be set to in my `database.yml` file. How can I find out which IP address and port to set it to?  When I had the project on my windows operating system I was able to configure it to `host:localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to find the listed default gateway.  So I opened up terminal on Ubuntu and used the following command: `netstat -rn`. That gave the following result...

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

From there I noticed the Default Gateway was `10.0.2.2`. I setup my database.yml as follows:

```
development:    
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: 10.0.2.2
  database: Development
  username: username12345
  password: password12345
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

And the connection worked!  Hope this helps someone else in a similar situation.

**EDIT:**

So I ran into a very similar problem when attempting to do this same setup on a computer where the host was running SQLExpress.  Below I'll outline some of the things that I did to get it working since it was a little different of a process.

1. You have to enable the TCP/IP connection (in a couple of places) and specify the port being used.

   Go To: `Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager`.  Then expand `SQL SERVER NETWORK CONFIGURATION` and enable all the protocols in the right pane. Now, right click and select `Properties` from `TCP/IP` from the right-pane. Under the `Protocol` tab make sure "Enabled" is set to "Yes".  Under `IP Address` tab I made sure all the IPs were set to "Yes" for `Enabled` and `Active`.  Finally, I added my port `1433` to IP8 which was my `127.0.0.1` IP and also to the `IP All` at the very bottom of the scroll box.  Once that was applied and I restarted the server via SQL Server Management Studio (right click the connection once connected and select "restart") I was able to connect!
2. I also used a slightly different `database.yml` file.

```
development:  
  adapter: sqlserver  
  dataserver: 10.0.2.2:1433    
  host: 10.0.2.2  
  port: 1433  
  database: Development  
  username: username12345  
  password: password12345  
  pool: 5  
  timeout: 5000
```

3. Finally, remember to give the user the right permissions.